# Passing a function as parameter in flutter with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

After upgrading to Flutter 1.25.0-8.1.pre null safety is enabled by default and I started to modify the code of my project. Everything is working fine except functions passed as parameters like in the following example:

```
class AppBarIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Function onPressed;
  const AppBarIcon({Key? key, required this.icon, required this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoButton(
      child: Icon(icon, size: 28, color: Colors.white),
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

*onPressed* is a required parameter so it cannot be null but nevertheless I get an error when trying to pass the function to the *CupertinoButton*:

`The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.`

I am already searching quite long for an answer and a possible solution but I haven't found one yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a `Function()` value to a `void Function()` parameter like it says.  Change your declaration to `final void Function() onPressed;` so that the typing is a closer match and can't possibly return a null or take args.

Comment: Yes you always need to add the void keyword before `Function`, even though dart static analysis does not give an error.

Answer (score 4):

You could have just added the parenthesis to the function declaration like so, `Function()` the updated code is below.

```
class AppBarIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Function() onPressed;
  const AppBarIcon({Key? key, required this.icon, required this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoButton(
      child: Icon(icon, size: 28, color: Colors.white),
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should include `void` otherwise `Function()` would return `dynamic`.

Comment: @IBRAHIM ALI MUSAH thanks a lot. you saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `VoidCallback` instead of `void Function()`, and create your own for the ones which isn't defined.

```dart
class FooWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed; // Required
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context) builder; // Required 
  final VoidCallback? onLongPress; // Optional (nullable)

  FooWidget({
    required this.onPressed, 
    required this.builder, 
    this.onLongPress, 
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      onLongPress: onLongPress,
      child: builder(context),
    );
  }
}
```